# Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: discussion

I can understand [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1353582/931000) being downvoted but my one and only [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1346582/very-slow-sshd-in-ahci-mode-affecting-windows-only) was also downvoted almost at the same time? Weeks after the fact?

And it's weird that in the "achievements" menu both have a -2 but opening the pages it shows -1???

Please give suggestion for improvement. Thank you.

Comment: @n8te Ok, that makes sense. I should said I wrote this in a hurry (and slightly p***** off). I should have though of that. So, now I have two persons against me, nice (not).

Comment: @n8te Yeah, sure, but it's frustrating. What bugs me the most is it being almost simultaneously like if someone deliberately went in a hunting expedition. If I'm doing something wrong I would very much like to be told what it is.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397 What, is this for real? Very funny and thank you for posting that as it certainly made me calm down a little :)

Comment: And now I have 3 points making it 0 again? Well, thank you voters, whoever you are.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's reassuring.

Comment: All my points have already been made, but about your referenced answer: you say you understand why that might be downvoted, but you don't say what that is.  In general, saying something can't be done will often come back and bite you in the butt when someone else posts a "thinking outside the box" solution.  For example, there are a number of editors that would allow you to embed the PDF pages on new PDF pages that have numbers.  So even if you can't change the original pages, you can still achieve the result.  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, observations like that answer, especially without authoritative citation, are more suited as a comment because they aren't a solution or definitive answer.  At this point, you have lots of options.  You could move it to a comment and delete the answer (and get the rep back).  You could expand or change the answer to make it better.  You could simply delete it.  Nothing says that once you post a brilliant pearl of wisdom, and it turns out to be not a great as it seemed at the time, you have to just leave it there as-is.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks. Well, I know PDFs can be edited but the OP said *it is not editable* and, checking the profile I noticed the person is a software engineer so I assumed such person was aware of the existence of Acrobat or others, couldn't or didn't want to use that and was looking for some other solution... But I understand your point and already deleted it.

Comment: Answers are for all future readers looking for a solution to the same problem. When you answer, try to make it applicable to the most people possible, rather than tailoring it to the perceived knowledge of the OP. E.g., on a technical solution for an OP who is advanced, it doesn't hurt to include explanation for the novices who will read it later. It's also a good idea to include any assumptions you've made since the next reader may not recognize the limitations of the answer. Answers that teach tend to get a lot more upvotes than brief answers tailored to the OP.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Very good point, sir. Many thanks. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: It also helps when you follow-up on anything you post within the Super User realm.  Yesterday, you posted a comment related to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1353546/650163) and two people specifically asked you questions regarding that comment, yet you never replied.

Comment: @Run5k Sorry about that, I was probably confused and the comment was inappropriate. Now deleted so it doesn't hurt the question.

Answer (score 8):

> Please give a suggestion on how to improve the question.

I will preface this answer by the fact I have absolutely no skin in the game.

> [image]

I read your question several times, and I see a narrative that has little to do with your actual question, which is simply you successfully switched from *Native IDE* to *AHCI* and the result was a performance issue with a secondary drive.  You should consider removing the narrative that isn't required, present the facts quickly, and just give us the meat and the potatoes.  *If somebody asks for some of the sides then provide it at that time in the form of a transparent edit to the question.*

However, once I get through the narrative that has little to do with the odd performance hit you encountered, I am left with no information on your hardware.  Which means I cannot research if more people reported issues with AHCI mode with that particular SSHD.

The type of information I am looking for with regards to the SSHD in order to answer your question, is that exact model of the SSHD in the device, something the AliExpress product page does not specify. You mention switching to AHCI mode, which requires drivers but didn't provide any information about those drivers.  Depending on the instructions you used, you could have used drivers that are incompatible with Windows 10, but nobody reading your question could confirm that fact.  There are several AHCI controllers on the market, if you had indicated which one the device had, people might have suggested using a more recent driver.

There are also upwards of 8 grammatical mistakes that Grammarly has flagged.  While they are small issues, when combined with no specifics about SSHD, and the extremely wordy narrative and you have yourself a candidate for a contribution that should be improved.  You also tagged the question, with the Ubuntu tag, which has little to do with your actual question.

> I can understand this answer being downvoted but the only question I have asked was also downvoted almost at the same time? Weeks after the fact?

You received 2 downvotes and 2 upvotes, and have received a single answer, which indicates your question has issues.  You should take the downvote to heart, make some improvements to the question, allowing those that downvoted your question to reverse their vote.  **If you don't improve your question, those people who issued a vote, cannot reverse their vote.**

You also seem to have been happy with the single answer you received, per a comment I got the impression, you actually considered it as answering your question.  You get reputation points for accepting an answer.  **By doing that it would have nearly negated the reputation you lost from the two downvotes by the way.**